# get dates of present month in a list and difference in dates

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

How do I go about printing these:

1. At any given time, I should be able to return the dates of the present month in a list.
   eg.  Since this is March, I want to print a list `[20140301, ...,20140331]`.
2. Find the difference in number of days from current date and the first of that month.

   e.g. today is 4th March.  I should be able to print the difference as 3
   Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: IMO the question is tagged "python" and it is clearly asking how to print dates of the current month. Not sure why this should be closed under the grounds that the "question is unclear"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do in Python 2.7.3

```
from datetime import date 
import calendar
today = date.today()

first_of_month = today.replace(day=1)
_, number_of_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(first_of_month.year, first_of_month.month)

for i in range(1, number_of_days_in_month+1):
    newdate = today.replace(day = i)
    print newdate #prints all dates in months

#Lets calculate difference between 14th of this month and 1st
randomdate = today.replace(day=14)
delta = randomdate - first_of_month
print delta.days
```